# Accessing Json data through api with Python

Tags: python, json, api, web-scraping, economics

I'm trying to access the Atlas Observatory of Economic Complexity API at this location:
http://atlas.media.mit.edu/about/api/data/

Using the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from urllib2 import urlopen
import csv as csv
import json


url = "http://atlas.media.mit.edu/hs/export/2010/show/all/all/"
mydata=open(urllib2.urlopen(url))
response = json.loads(mydata)
```

To which I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-fbe696d9098d> in <module>()
      8 
      9 url = "http://atlas.media.mit.edu/hs/export/2010/show/all/all/"
---> 10 mydata=open(urlopen(url))
     11 response = json.loads(mydata)
     12 

TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found
```

I'm new to accessing data from API's via python so there may be something simple I am missing. The goal is to get trade data and put it into a pandas data frame. As a bonus if anyone has any good sources for working with APIs in python please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using `requests`, http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/. It can be installed via pip and is a very clean interface built on top of urllib2.

```
import requests
url = "http://atlas.media.mit.edu/hs/export/2010/show/all/all/"
response = requests.get(url)
mydata = response.text
```

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. However, what do I do with the data in mydata at the end...I just get "u'{\n  "data": [\n    {\n      "export_val": 44456016199.05,\n"       and so on. How do I get that into a tabular format such as a data frame?

Comment: can `import json` and call `json.loads()` on the json string to yield a dictionary, then `use pandas.DataFrame.from_dict()` to put it into pandas.